# Проясните момент с мягким знаком

Tags: орфография

**Правило**: Мягкий знак пишется после согласных перед гласными е, ё, и, ю, я. Например: платье, жилье, воробьи, вьюга, братья. А как же школьница, учительница?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мягкий знак пишется не только перед гласными е, ё, и, ю, я.

[**Правописание разделительных Ь и Ъ**](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/tbgramota/45_68)

> Разделительный **Ь** пишется внутри слова (в корне или суффиксе, но только не после приставки) перед буквами Е, Ё, Ю, Я, И (ВЬЮГА, БУРЬЯН, ЛИСЬИ СЛЕДЫ), а также в некоторых заимствованных (иностранных) словах перед буквой О (БУЛЬОН, СИНЬОР, ГИЛЬОТИНА). Мягкий знак обычно **смягчает предшествующий ему согласный звук** и, кроме этого, заставляет нас произносить дополнительный звук [Й]

Если не смягчать согласный и, соответственно, не писать мягкий знак, то получатся другие слова, например: ***сплавь — сплав, мазь — МАЗ, хрень — хрен***.

В словах *школьница* и *учительница* произносится мягкий звук *Л*. Это отображается на письме с помощью *Ь*.

Comment: если у нас есть слово с приставкой мягкий знак писать не надо верно ?

Comment: @Leks Да, если приставка оканчивается на согласную, то после нее пишется твердый знак Ъ перед гласными Е, Ё, Ю, Я. Есть другие варианты, когда не нужно писать никакого знака после приставки. См. ссылку в ответе.

Comment: Может быть приставка из одной буквы ?

Comment: Да, например, СЪЕЗД.

Comment: вьюга тут в приставка ?

Comment: Нет,  ВЬЮГ - корень, А - окончание.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец, а как же собственно вопрос — шко**ль**ница, учите**ль**ница? Здесь ведь нет после мягкого знака никаких гласных (долька, пальчик, нельзя, бельмо).

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова В ответе я выделил жирным про смягчение согласного.

Comment: все равно остаются вопросы про школьницу

Comment: Как мне понять перед какими заимствованными словами у которых есть о писать мягкий знак ?

Comment: В русском языке есть нормы произношения, которые отражаются на письме. Если мы скажем ШКОЛНИЦА с твердым Л, то будем выглядеть как неносители языка или людьми с дефектами речи.

Comment: Если у меня есть дефект речи мне можно так произносить ?

Comment: В любом случае словари - всегда в помощь. Мы не можем сказать правильно БУЛЬОН  без Ь, получится БУЛОН. Правописание иностранных слов закрепляется словарями.

Comment: Скажите я правильно понял что в таких словах как школьница единственный способ проверки это вынимать мягкий знак ?

Comment: Человеку с неправильной (с точки зрения статистической нормы) артикуляцией никто не запрещает произносить слова так, как он может.

Comment: Твердые и мягкие звуки, обозначающиеся одной  буквой, различаются на слух.  Проверить всегда очень быстро можно с помощью поисковика.

Answer (score 2):

Обозначение мягкости согласного Л: внутри слова мягкий знак ставится после мягкого Л, стоящего перед **любым согласным** (твёрдым или мягким).
Ль**д**ина, ль**в**енок, ль**с**тец, аль**ф**а, пиль**щ**ик, пуль**с**ар, фаль**ш**ь, паль**ч**ик, паль**б**а, паль**м**а, паль**т**о, сель**с**кий, боль**ш**ак, коль**р**аби, **бездельник, насильник, холодильник,** фоль**г**а, сколь**ж**ение, поль**з**а, оль**х**а.

Мягкий знак не пишется между двумя мягкими Л: иллюзия, аллюр.

[Мягкий знак](https://uchitel.pro/%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA/)

Comment: Людмила, а как же, например, полка?

Comment: Римма я. Здесь Л твердый; мягкий — полька.

Comment: Да, извините, я просто обратил внимание только на перед **любым согласным**.

Comment: Ой, простите, на имя не посмотрел, только на зеленый значок. Спать пора! Голосую за Ваш ответ!